# acess a protect folder using sudo in wsl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i'm using linux shell in my windows (wsl) and i'm trying to make a `cd` to a directory that needs permission.

I've saw some solutions here including using `sudo su`, to became a super user, but even with this code i'm not sucessful

```
sudo su
cd ./rootfs
```

I'm stuck in this problem fro a while, so what's is going on?

```
root@LAPTOP-FGSL14B2:/mnt/c/Users/giova/Appdata/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState# cd ./rootfs

bash: cd: ./rootfs: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you open a Windows explorer and look at the properties/security of your `%Appdata%`?

Comment: they're all enabled! for system and for my user too

Answer (score 1):

It is a special folder, see: superuser.com/a/1446574/1083266

(I wanted to mark the question as a duplicate, but that is only valid for existing answers on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the folder you are trying to access required elevated permissions to view. Is the shell running as admin? 
Sudo will not elevate the shell to allow for access to windows folders that the process does not have access to.

In the start menu right click the wsl or bash exe and select "run as admin" see if that works for you.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. When I acess the folder by file manager it opens with no problem, but when I try to acess by bash don't

Comment: Can you access using powershell or cmd?

Comment: yes, with powershell I managed to change the directory for that folder!